# Django Question

Tags: python, django

Can you take things like the poll app from the tutorial and display them in an iframe or frameset? The tutorial is great and the app is very nice, but, how often do you go to a site with a whole page dedicated to a poll? I was trying to think about how you do it using the urls.py file, but couldn't wrap my head around it. Just wondering if anyone has done this or knows of any tutorials that cover this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Placing poll data in an extra iframe won't be necessary. You can write a templatetag, to display it on everywhere you need to.

**edit**

The chapter ["inclusion tags"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) refers to the poll example app.

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 0):

Put the poll page in its own view, connect to the view via urls.py, and set up your frame or iframe to source from that URL.